# Incrementing/decrementing values in a list given specified range (Very green at Python)

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment for an introductory Python class and the objective is to prompt the user for a password, determine it fits the given criteria, then encrypt the password by converting the characters to decimal, incrementing the letters and numbers, and decrementing the characters "!@#$" then return the new encrypted password. EX. an input of "123ABCabc$" should output "234BCDbcd#" **EDIT -> fixed this output per @gimix

I have everything up to the step of incrementing/decrementing and this last step has me pulling my hair out. I have tried a gang of different things but the two closest to successful attempts I have are as follows.

-in the first sample new_input is the users original input

-in the second sample use_ascii is new_input converted to decimal

1)

```
def encrypt(new_input):
    encrypted = ''
    for char in new_input:
        if chr(ord(char)) in list(range(97,123)): #ive tried different formatting options, thus the inconsistency 
            encrypted += chr(ord(char) + 1)
        if chr(ord(char)) > str(64):
            encrypted += chr(ord(char) + 1)
        if chr(ord(char)) >= str(48):
            encrypted += chr(ord(char) + 1)
        if chr(ord(char)) == str(64):
            encrypted += chr(ord(char) - 1)
        if chr(ord(char)) >= str(32):
            encrypted += chr(ord(char) - 1)
    return encrypted
```

2. 

---

```
def encrypt(use_ascii):
    encr = ''
    list1 = list(range(97,123))
    list2 = list(range(48,58))
    list3 = list(range(56,91))
    list4 = list(range(30,35))
    for i in use_ascii:
        if i in list1:
            encr = i + 1
        if i in list2:
            encr = i + 1
        if i in list3:
            use_ascii = i + 1
        if i in list4:
            use_ascii = i - 1
    return encr
```

then my main statements are (swapping 'use_ascii' for 'new_pass' when i test different options)...

```
new_input = input('Please input a password: \n')
new_encr = encrypt(use_ascii)
print('Your encrypted password is: {}'.format(encrypt(use_ascii)))
```

**EDIT per Jasmijn

Sample 1 outputs:  just errors and I havn't been trying to fix it as much as I suspect that is the less-correct way to proceed

Sample 2 outputs: Your encrypted password is: 100

This is dec for the letter 'd' which suggests it is selecting the last character which fits the criteria of the first 'if' statement and incrementing it. I need it to increment each character and output the new decimal based on the ranges provided.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please explain clearly what the problem is, and what you are getting instead of the expected output.

Comment: Right! I will edit my post with that.

Comment: "Incrementing letters and numbers"... but in your example you convert `123` to `/12`: this is _decrementing_ (and then it should be `012`). The same holds for `ABC` => `@AB`, and for `abc` => `'ab`. In other words you are decrementing everything.

Comment: @gimix - Thank you for pointing that out. I mistyped and will edit that when I am back at my PC shortly. That said, I am still unsure how to write the functions to change each character according to the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `isalnum()` string method to distinguish between letters/numbers an special characters. So you could simply do:

```
def encrypt(instring):
    outstring = ''
    for ch in instring:
        outstring += chr(ord(ch)+1) if ch.isalnum() else chr(ord(ch)-1)
    return outstring
```

Or, if you want a one-liner:

```
def encrypt(instring):
    return ''.join((chr(ord(ch)+1) if ch.isalnum() else chr(ord(ch)-1) for ch in instring))
```

Comment: This is the ticket!!! Thank you! I spent 4 hours last night and another 4 hours this morning trying to figure out how to write it and it all is just that simple. Thus the learning process. Next step is to properly understand what is going on in that line, but that will come with time. Wicked appreciated!

Comment: Well, since it is an assignment I guess you better stick to the first version for now :)